# Is this the correct way to use a trig identity in calculus?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find zeros to test for concavity. I was given $f'(x)=2\cos x+\sin2x$

I found the 2nd derivative: $f"(x)=-2\sin x+2\cos2x$

Can i use the identity $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$?

So would it be $-2\sin x+2-4\sin^2x
=-2\sin x(2\sin x+2)$
??

Answer (score 0):

$$-4u^2 - 2u  +2 = -2(2u-1)(u+1)$$

So
$$
-4\sin^2 x -2\sin x + 2 = -2(2\sin x -1)(\sin x + 1)
$$

You can factor like that, but whether it's useful depends on what you're trying to do.  Sometimes one wants to know for which values of $x$ the derivative is positive, and factoring is that thing to do if that is the question.